# Redirecting URL with parameters in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, parameters

How could I redirect the following URL from my site to an other website (URL wth parameters too) using the .htaccess?

Example:

Redirect

```
 http://mysite.com.br/page/?r=17dzhZ3JG5jfKMd45BowS1Pr1cH9FW8zzK
```

to

```
 http://anothersite.com.br/?r=1vEe4mDd94JQLCCTnX3Cdzy2KFfH6eKbS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the htaccess file on mysite.com.br's document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^r=17dzhZ3JG5jfKMd45BowS1Pr1cH9FW8zzK$
RewriteRule ^page/?$ http://anothersite.com.br/?r=1vEe4mDd94JQLCCTnX3Cdzy2KFfH6eKbS [L,R]
```